# Kafka connect MongoDB sink connector using kafka-avro-console-producer

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to write some documents to MongoDB using the Kafka connect MongoDB connector. I've managed to set up all the components required and start up the connector but when I send the message to Kafka using the kafka-avro-console-producer, Kafka connect is giving me the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Error: `operationType` field is doc is missing.
```

I've tried to add this field to the message but then kafka connect is asking me to include a documentKey field. It seems like I need to include some extra fields apart from the payload defined in my schema but I can't find a comprehensive documentation. Does anyone have an example of a kafka message payload (using kafka-avro-console-producer) that goes through a Kafka -> Kafka connect -> MongoDB pipeline?

See following an example of one of the messages I'm sending to Kafka (btw, kafka-avro-console-consumer is able to consume the messages):

```
./kafka-avro-console-producer   --broker-list kafka:9093 --topic sampledata   --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"field1","type":"string"}]}'                                                                                                                                         
{"field1": "value1"}
```

And see also following the configuration of the sink connector:

```
{"name": "mongo-sink",
      "config": {
         "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
         "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",     "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schemaregistry:8081",
         "connection.uri":"mongodb://cadb:27017",
         "database":"cognitive_assistant",
         "collection":"topicData",
         "topics":"sampledata6",
         "change.data.capture.handler": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.ChangeStreamHandler"
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please clarify what example you're following... `operationType` is in **your own schema** here, so if the examples you are following aren't not using that schema, that would explain why they do not add/need that field. You also have an error around `key.converter` since your console-producer is not sending Avro keys (or any key at all), so you should remove that property from the connect config (localhost is also not the schema registry address). Overall, focus on one error at a time. Forget connect; does `kafka-avro-console-consumer` work after you produce?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @OneCricketeer, my initial post was a bit confusing (sorry about that). I've edited it right now (hope that helps to better understand my issue). Thanks also for pointing out the key.converter issue, I've just removed that property (doesn't fix the issue though). Kafka-avro-console-consumer is showing the messages I send through the console.

Answer (score 2):

I've just managed to make the connector work. I deleted the change.data.capture.handler property from the connector configuration and it works now.